# Proper way to handle pivot data operations (via has_many "through")

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

In a basic blog application, I have an articles module which allows me to select the related categories.
There are 3 tables; articles, article_categories, categories. 2 models, `Model_Article` and `Model_Category` extending ORM with has-many 'through' relationship assigned accordingly. During 'Edit Article' form submission, what is the proper way (or better way) to:

- Retrieve all available `category ids` in array format to populate `Form::select()`
- Retrieve assigned `category ids` from pivot table, in array format for selected categories
- Update pivot table upon successful form submission, where some pivot data already exist. Preferably checking existing data before add/remove the relevant ones (instead of deleting all existing pivot data then adding all submitted `category ids`).

**Basically I'm hoping there's a way to get the pivot data arrays without looping through the ORM objects.**

Not sure if what I'm asking for can only be done via database prepared statements/query builder. If so, is it advisable for me to have my own methods (using prepared statements/query builder) added to my `Model_Article extend ORM`?

The current method I'm using are:

**Get all category ids**

```
    $categories_orm = ORM::factory('article_category')->find_all();
    foreach($categories_orm as $category_orm) {
        $categories[$category_orm->id] = $category_orm->name;
    }
```

**Get selected category ids**

```
    $categories_current = $article->article_categories->find_all();
    foreach($categories_current as $category){
        $categories_selected = $category->id;
    }
```

**Update category ids**

```
    $categories_orm = $article->article_categories->find_all();
    $categories_existing = array();
    foreach($categories_orm as $category){
        $categories_existing[] = $category->id;
    }
    $categories_selected = $this->request->post('category');

    $categories_to_remove = array_diff($categories_existing,$categories_selected);
    $categories_to_add = array_diff($categories_selected,$categories_existing);
    if(!empty($categories_to_remove)) {
        $article->remove('article_categories', $categories_to_remove);
    }
    if(!empty($categories_to_add)) {
        $article->add('article_categories', $categories_to_add);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably rename your relationship table to `articles_categories` (both plural) to follow Kohana conventions, and `categories` is a better alias for the relationship.

The category model should be used to retrieve all category ID's. Then you loop through it the same as your example to populate an array.

**Get all categories.**

```
$categories_orm = ORM::factory('category')->find_all();
foreach ($categories_orm as $category)
{
    $categories[$categories_orm->id] = $categories_orm->name;   
}
```

Make sure your select element gives post values in an array by naming it like this:

```
name="categories[]"
```

**Update relationships.**

```
$article = ORM::factory('article', $post['article_id']);

// do stuff (validate, update the article etc.)

// remove all relationships
$article->remove('categories');

// add new relationships
$article->add('categories', $post['categories']);
```

I would probably use hidden form fields to check against to first verify if the categories relationship needs to be updated. I'd imagine the categories for an article rarely ever change.